# Select multiple categories from CPT to display in LayersWP builder widget

Tags: custom-taxonomy, widgets, forms

I am currently developing a LayersWP child theme and have registered a portfolio custom builder widget.

In this widget I would like users to be able to select the categories that they want shown. For example:

> A user has multiple portfolio items. One in the category ”Art”, one in
>   the category “Design” and one in the category “Development”. On the
>   homepage the user only wants to show portfolio items in the category
>   “Design” and “Art”.

The default LayersWP widget only lets you choose one specific category to show, and it's not possible to select multiple categories. I would like to build this into my widget but can’t really find anything about it in the LayersWP docs.

I am kind of struggling on how to save the categories that are selected.

Currently this is my code markup:

```
$terms = get_terms( $this->taxonomy );
if( ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) { ?>
    <p class="layers-form-item">
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'category' ); ?>"><?php 
            echo __( 'Category to Display' , LAYERS_THEME_SLUG ); ?></label>
        <?php $category_options[ 0 ] ="All";
        foreach ( $terms as $t ) 
            $category_options[ $t->term_id ] = $t->name;
        echo $this->form_elements()->input(
            array(
                'type' => 'select',
                'name' => $this->get_field_name( 'category' ) ,
                'id' => $this->get_field_id( 'category' ) ,
                'placeholder' => __( 'Select a Category' , LAYERS_THEME_SLUG ),
                'value' => ( isset( $categories ) ) ? $categories : NULL ,
                'options' => $category_options
            ) 
        ); ?>
    </p>
<?php } // if !is_wp_error ?>
```

How exactly do I give users the option to select multiple categories in this builder widget, and then save the categories that are selected?